# Android Studio import facebook library odyssey

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

I am trying to use Facebook login in my App with the Facebook library in Android Studio.

After following 9 tutorials about how to import that library on Android Studio 0.6.1 , all was going well (on the last tutorial) before click on clean project, after click on it I am getting this error:

```
 *C:\Users\Demetria\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\libreries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookA    ppLinkResolver.java
Error:(21, 13) error: package bolts does not exist   
Error:(37, 49) error: cannot find symbol class AppLinkResolver        
Error:(57, 12) error: cannot find symbol class Task          
Error:(63, 42) error: cannot find symbol class Continuation             
Error:(105, 83) error: cannot find symbol variable Task               
Error:(192, 27) error: package AppLink does not exist*
```

Could anyone help me please?.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Using Facebook SDK 3.22 in latest version of Android Studio][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24573831/2314592

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you imported the library via `File > Import Module`, Android Studio copied that `facebook` directory into your project.  The `$PROJECT_ROOT/facebook/build.gradle` file references `bolts.jar`:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('../libs/bolts.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
}
```

Note that in the unziped archive from Facebook, there is a `libs` folder in the parent folder (the `..` path) of the library.  In your project, you need to point at the `libs` folder *in the facebook library folder*.  Change `..` to `.` as below:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('./libs/bolts.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have just do it and when I trying to do the imports on my class , for example import com.facebook.LoggingBehavior,  I have this new error 
Error: package com.facebook does not exist

Comment: In mi case works with this
  dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile files('/libs/bolts.jar')
}

Answer (score 0):

To build successfully the latest Facebook SDK with Android Studio, you also need to indicate to the build.gradle from the Facebook SDK to compile the bolt jar.

See my detailed post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466921/android-studio-0-8-1-how-to-use-facebook-sdk/24885195#24885195)