# Facebook-sdk not working after androidstudio update to 0.8.1

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, updates, android-gradle-plugin

I'm working on an android application that uses facebook sdk 3.6.0, in android studio 0.5.7, after  update to 0.8.1 ... facebook sdk does not work, 
 the following error appears :

```
 07-14 11:39:59.808      544-544/com.example.testdrawer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testdrawer/com.example.testdrawer.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at comm.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
            at com.example.testdrawer.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:65)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
 

    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)

                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
                at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
                at com.example.testdrawer.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:65)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I also changed gradle from 9 to 12

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
```

How to solve this problem?

thank you!

I do not know exactly what I did, but it works !

I cleaned the project (**build-clear project**) and I changed something in build.grandle

```
  apply plugin: 'android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 14
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

Comment: Is the Facebook SDK correctly setup as a dependency of your module?

Comment: Following the steps from this answer solved this crash for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24573831/1020571

Comment: tanks, I fixed the problem :)

Comment: Its always better to work on the latest version. Android studio has reached the 1.0.x version. Try it. ;)