# Android Studio 0.8.2 Import Module

Tags: android, android-studio, foursquare

I am trying to import my clone of https://github.com/condesales/easyFoursquare4Android into android studio by following [Android Studio 0.8.1 - how to use Facebook SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466921/android-studio-0-8-1-how-to-use-facebook-sdk) but in this case there is no foursquare folder.

When I try to reimport it says "location already imported".  I was importing from

%MY_HOME%\AndroidStudioProjects\EasyFourSquareApp

which contain the EasyFourSquareApp library and the EasyFourSquareApp example.

I also don't see a refresh project button in Android Studio like in Eclipse, I hit synchronize and still dont see any foursquare folders.

Answer (score 0):

In NavigationBar ,Threr are two options bellow "Build"

```
Build -> Rebuild Project
      ->   Clean Project
```