# Import Facebook SDK on the Android Studio 0.8.6

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

Does anybody knows how to Import the Facebook SDK on the 0.8.6 version?
In fact, I tried to import as Module the Facebook SDK, but the Facebook is not showing up as a library.

Error:(9) A problem occurred evaluating project ':facebook'.

> Could not find property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION' on project ':facebook'.

Also, on the Module Settings it is not showing as a module

Comment: I just found out from this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466921/android-studio-0-8-1-how-to-use-facebook-sdk

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24573831/2314592

Answer (score 10):

I know this is a late response to your question but this might help other people.

Facebook's "build.gradle" file assumes that you have a "gradle.properties" file where the ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION variable is declared. So all you have to do is create a file called "gradle.properties" in the root level and add the following to it.

```
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=19
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=20.0.0
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=19
ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=11
```

You can also define other variables in this file and access those variables in your "build.gradle" file. Example: project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION