# Install Facebook SDK in Android Studio 0.8.14

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-studio

Hey there I have been searching for an answer to this on stack overflow and google but nothing seems to be up to date for the newest android studio and the old answers aren't working So I am wondering if someone could help me out here?

Theses don't work

[Android Studio 0.8.1 - how to use Facebook SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466921/android-studio-0-8-1-how-to-use-facebook-sdk)
[using facebook sdk in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio)
http://trinitytuts.com/integrating-facebook-sdk-application-android-studio/

Thanks for the help in advance.

**EDIT**

I get this error
[image]

This is my settings.gradle file

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For you can add the sdk of facebook in your project with Android Studio.

You only need follow this steps:

- Download the SDK of Facebook at [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/)
- Copy the folder **facebook** in your root project.
- You need set this folder how to module. Go to the file **settings.gradle** and include this ':name_of_folder'
- Now only need put this line in your **app.gradle** `    compile project (':name_of_folder')

That's all.

Ok, this error is very common. You will need set this global variables in your **settings.gradle**

```
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=19
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=19
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=1
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply but I get the error above (seen in edit)

Comment: @iqueqiorio I edit my post. If I fix the problem pless check correct answer. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
     dependencies { 
 compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1' 
}
```

[Install Facebook SDK in latest Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24573831/2314592)