# Get value from strings.xml in Facebook SDK

Tags: java, android, xml, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am setting up my app with Facebook login and am trying to get some of the pre set strings and colors from the Facebook SDK and use them in my activity_login.xml. Something like this

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"

    android:text="@string/com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button"
    android:textColor="@color/com_facebook_loginview_text_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/com_facebook_loginview_text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold"

    android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_button_blue"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/com_facebook_inverse_icon"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/com_facebook_likebutton_compound_drawable_padding"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/com_facebook_loginview_padding_left"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/com_facebook_loginview_padding_top"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/com_facebook_loginview_padding_right"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/com_facebook_loginview_padding_bottom"
    android:onClick="onLoginClick"/>
```

But I get an error `Cant resolve symbol @string/com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button` and I have imported the Facebook SDK correctly and it is good, but I can't seem to use the values?

Thanks for the help in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't use the Facebook button?

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/facebook_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Make sure you import Facebook SDK into your project for this to work.

Comment: Yes cause I get this error when I use it `3650-3677/com.spencerfontein.ueat E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)`

Comment: Are you instantiating it with a Facebook button as well?

Comment: I did this to install it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233722/install-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio-0-8-14. And on a side note I am just trying to setup Facebook login if you know a good tutorial or could answer that...? Thanks

Comment: I used this one a few weeks ago and it works fine. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.2