# Android Studio Gradle build error while adding Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, gradle

Hi am getting the following error while adding facebook sdk to my project
Tried the following post for configuring the gradle script for facebook sdk

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466921/android-studio-0-8-1-how-to-use-facebook-sdk)

```
Error:(111) A problem occurred evaluating project ':facebook'.
> Cannot call getBootClasspath() before setTargetInfo() is called.
```

This is my facebook module gradle script

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

project.group = 'com.facebook.android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:[21,22)'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

def isSnapshot = version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')
def ossrhUsername = hasProperty('NEXUS_USERNAME') ? NEXUS_USERNAME : ""
def ossrhPassword = hasProperty('NEXUS_PASSWORD') ? NEXUS_PASSWORD : ""

task setVersion {
    // The version will be derived from source
    project.version = null
    def sdkVersionFile = file('src/com/facebook/FacebookSdkVersion.java')
    sdkVersionFile.eachLine{
        def matcher = (it =~ /(?:.*BUILD = \")(.*)(?:\".*)/)
        if (matcher.matches()) {
          project.version = matcher[0][2]
          return
        }
    }
    if (project.version.is('unspecified')) {
      throw new GradleScriptException('Version could not be found.', null)
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

        repository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/") {
            authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
        }

        snapshotRepository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
            authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
        }

        pom.project {
            name 'Facebook-Android-SDK'
            artifactId = 'facebook-android-sdk'
            packaging 'aar'
            description 'Facebook Android SDK'
            url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'

            scm {
                connection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
                developerConnection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
                url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'
            }

            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                    url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/LICENSE.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }

            developers {
                developer {
                    id 'facebook'
                    name 'Facebook'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

uploadArchives.dependsOn(setVersion)

signing {
    required { !isSnapshot && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
    sign configurations.archives
}

task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
}

artifacts {
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocsJar
}

afterEvaluate {
    androidJavadocs.classpath += project.android.libraryVariants.toList().first().javaCompile.classpath
}
```

Please help....

Comment: Post top `build.gradle`.

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your issue: `Cannot call getBootClasspath() before setTargetInfo() is called.`, I believe has been solved here:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Android Build tools `1.1.0` created this problem and they fixed it in `1.1.1`:

> 1.1.1 (2015/02/24)
>
> - Only variants that package a Wear app will now trigger building them.
> - Dependency related issues now fail at build time rather than at debug time.
> - This is to allow running diagnostic tasks (such as 'dependencies') to help resolve the conflict.
> - **Calling android.getBootClasspath() is now possible again.**

Please upgrade to: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'`, for example:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem! Anytime. :P

Comment: I tried this, and solved the issue..but now I am getting Gradle dsl method not found. classpath(). Actually I updated the build.gradle dependecies of facebook..is that right?..

Comment: @sarath If you updated your class path for Android build.gradle, it should have fixed that issue. I am not sure about Facebook.