# Error:(10, 0) gradle method not found classpath()

Tags: android, facebook, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Hello i'm newbie with Android studio , i imported facebook as, and first i got this error  `Error:(111)  Cannot call getBootClasspath() before setTargetInfo() is called.` and i followed the right answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29187973/android-studio-gradle-build-error-while-adding-facebook-sdk). i.e i changed my depencies from

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:[21,22)'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4'
}
```

to

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
    }
```

and now i'm getting this error

```
   Error:(10, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'classpath()'
Possible causes:The project 'FiberTeccpcp' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
        Gradle settings
The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
        Apply Gradle plugin
```

**finally this is my build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

project.group = 'com.facebook.android'

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'
......
```

How can i correct this?

Comment: Post your top level build gradle file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include this part in the `buildscript` block

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
}
```

Should be:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
    }
}
```