# Android Studio, Facebook SDK login

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk

I need to use login with facebook using FacebookSDK but I really don't understand the doc in the developper website of facebook, it's not user-friendly...

I put the log in button correctly, and the user can connect with his account. But I don't understand how to delete the button when the account is used, and how to display the name of the user into the app ?

Other question, is there a solution to put some data (like preference specific to my app) into his account ? For example, he use checkbox to say "i like basketball". And when he disconnect and reconnect, the checkbox is still active. is there a solution to use a database with facebook API ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: follow this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24573831/4693713

Comment: This is not a problem the SDK installation....