# Android Studio - Could not find com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to incluide FaceBook Sdk 4.2 in my app. When I import this module , it´s all rigth, but when my app run the following occurs:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':Glam Main'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':Glam Main:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Users/JL9/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/parse/bolts/bolts-android/1.2.0/bolts-android-1.2.0.pom
         file:/C:/Users/JL9/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/parse/bolts/bolts-android/1.2.0/bolts-android-1.2.0.jar
         file:/C:/Users/JL9/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/parse/bolts/bolts-android/1.2.0/bolts-android-1.2.0.pom
         file:/C:/Users/JL9/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/parse/bolts/bolts-android/1.2.0/bolts-android-1.2.0.jar
     Required by:
         Glam Main:Glam Main:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook:4.2.0
```

**gradle.Module.Glam Main:Glam Main:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':appcompat_v7_21')
    compile project(':appcompat_v7_21-cardview')
    compile project(':appcompat_v7_21-recyclerview')
    compile project(':httpmime-4.2.6')
    compile project(':facebook')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

*In my module Facebook , I have added `com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0`. this module Facebook has been imported correctly because i can work with their classes.*

Here my **gradle.Module.Facebook**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {

    mavenCentral()
}

project.group = 'com.facebook.android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:[22,23)'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
        targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

def isSnapshot = version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')
def ossrhUsername = hasProperty('NEXUS_USERNAME') ? NEXUS_USERNAME : ""
def ossrhPassword = hasProperty('NEXUS_PASSWORD') ? NEXUS_PASSWORD : ""

task setVersion {
    // The version will be derived from source
    project.version = null
    def sdkVersionFile = file('src/com/facebook/FacebookSdkVersion.java')
    sdkVersionFile.eachLine{
        def matcher = (it =~ /(?:.*BUILD = \")(.*)(?:\".*)/)
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            project.version = matcher[0][1]
            return
        }
    }
    if (project.version.is('unspecified')) {
        throw new GradleScriptException('Version could not be found.', null)
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

        repository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/") {
            authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
        }

        snapshotRepository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
            authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
        }

        pom.project {
            name 'Facebook-Android-SDK'
            artifactId = 'facebook-android-sdk'
            packaging 'aar'
            description 'Facebook Android SDK'
            url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'

            scm {
                connection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
                developerConnection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
                url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'
            }

            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'Facebook Platform License'
                    url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/LICENSE.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }

            developers {
                developer {
                    id 'facebook'
                    name 'Facebook'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

uploadArchives.dependsOn(setVersion)

signing {
    required { !isSnapshot && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
    sign configurations.archives
}

task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    // JDK 1.8 is more strict then 1.7. Have JDK 1.8 behave like 1.7 for javadoc generation
    if (org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current().getJavaVersion() == JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8) {
        options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
    }
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
}

artifacts {
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocsJar
}

afterEvaluate {
    androidJavadocs.classpath += project.android.libraryVariants.toList().first().javaCompile.classpath}
```

I have read the follow post [Android Studio 0.8.1 - how to use Facebook SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466921/android-studio-0-8-1-how-to-use-facebook-sdk) but I getnt  resolve my problem. Thanks.

**Update 1**

I have modified **gradle.Module.Glam Main:Glam Main**. *I added this sentences:*

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

*Now i have this error*

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;

Error:Execution failed for task ':Glam Main:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the latest Facebook SDK via Gradle dependency:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0'
```

Take a look to my build.gradle file:

https://github.com/lalongooo/permutas-sep/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Comment: Dont work! *Error:(39, 13)  Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0*

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using? I recommend to install the latest one.

Comment: I´m using Android Studio 1.2.2 . Thanks!

Comment: I can't understand why you want to import the Facebook SDK as a module. Is there any difference of you include as a dependency?

Comment: This is my reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started Pay attention in the step 4 of the Android Studio Setup

section

Comment: I followed each steps. I think that Facebook SDk is incompatible with some   of my libraries .`UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes; but I dont found what is this library. Thanks for your help
`

Comment: Hey! Just found this article, hope this helps https://medium.com/sebs-top-tips/psa-fix-multidex-build-crashes-ae2b81bcf711