# gradle build error after adding facebook SDK as module dependency

Tags: gradle

I am using facebook-android-sdk-4.3.0. I have error after following steps of this solution [Android Studio 0.8.1 - how to use Facebook SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466921/android-studio-0-8-1-how-to-use-facebook-sdk)

M:\Myapp\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-xhdpi\com_facebook_button_send_icon.png: error: Duplicate file.

M:\Myapp\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\com_facebook_button_send_icon.png: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\saty\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Please suggest me how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem after following tutorial

https://trinitytuts.com/integrating-facebook-sdk-application-android-studio/

might be helpful for someone else.