# Facebook SDK "Package bolts does not exist error" Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-sdk-3.1

I am trying to add the Facebook login to my app using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio) method 
but am getting the following errors:

```
Error:(21, 13) error: package bolts does not exist
Error:(22, 13) error: package bolts does not exist
Error:(23, 13) error: package bolts does not exist
Error:(24, 13) error: package bolts does not exist
Error:(37, 49) error: cannot find symbol class AppLinkResolver
Error:(48, 32) error: cannot find symbol class AppLink
Error:(58, 12) error: cannot find symbol class Task
Error:(58, 17) error: cannot find symbol class AppLink
Error:(80, 12) error: cannot find symbol class Task
Error:(80, 26) error: cannot find symbol class AppLink  
Error:(182, 27) error: package AppLink does not exist
Error:(48, 75) error: cannot find symbol class AppLink
Error:(62, 9) error: cannot find symbol class Task
Error:(62, 23) error: cannot find symbol class AppLink
Error:(64, 42) error: cannot find symbol class Continuation
Error:(64, 64) error: cannot find symbol class AppLink
Error:(64, 74) error: cannot find symbol class AppLink
Error:(81, 24) error: cannot find symbol class AppLink
Error:(81, 67) error: cannot find symbol class AppLink
Error:(86, 13) error: cannot find symbol class AppLink
Error:(103, 20) error: cannot find symbol variable Task
Error:(106, 15) error: cannot find symbol class Task
Error:(106, 29) error: cannot find symbol class AppLink
Error:(106, 83) error: cannot find symbol variable Task
Error:(151, 45) error: package AppLink does not exist
Error:(151, 85) error: package AppLink does not exist
Error:(154, 44) error: package AppLink does not exist
Error:(161, 33) error: cannot find symbol class AppLink
Error:(161, 55) error: cannot find symbol class AppLink
Error:(196, 27) error: package AppLink does not exist
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457113/android-studio-import-facebook-library-odyssey) but the answer prescribes a solution for the import method of adding the Facebook SDK to a project. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved the problem by re-copying the `libs` folder which contains the `bolts.jar` file back to the Facebook module (Note that one of the instructions in the first link i provided in the question was to delete the libs folder) and then changing the following in the Facebook module's `build.gradle` file.

```
 compile files('../libs/bolts.jar')
```

to

```
  compile files('./libs/bolts.jar')
```

Note the single dot instead of double in the first one.
After that, perform the `sync project with gradle files` operation and the errors will disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Look at Facebook libs folder.

There is a bolts' jar.

Write this correct name into facebook build.gradle.

`compile files ('libs/<name_bolts_jar>.jar')`

In my project, the correct name is `bolts-android-1.1.2.jar.`

So, Sync your project with Gradle Files.

After this modifications, my app runs correctly.